# Vue - Routing to a subcomponent within a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue, I've got a component named  Container. It is composed of two components ComponentA and ComponentB. Here is the code for the Vue app Https:/codesandbox.io/s/p5po0jz47

How can a router be configured to navigate to ComponentB on ComponentA?

Comment: I dont think you can configure the router to do that, but you can always use `this.$router.push({  name: 'your componentB route' })`

Comment: Is there a way then to navigate to a section of a page? In the way you'd use # for non SPA applications?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge. The way I handled it was registering both components within the container, using the `<component></component>` tag in the container template, and using Vuex to manage the current `<component is="">` value.

So Component A may have a button to transition to Component B, which would then trigger a Vuex mutation that updates a Vuex state object like `{currentComponent: ""}`, then a Vuex getter would feed the `<component is="">` binding in the container component. There are easier ways to do this, I'm sure, but in my use case I wanted the selection persisted.